# GridView location of button how to determine the Cells[?] e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I placed a few Buttons above my GridView

I had read an article about doing this Update/Cancel buttons without having explicit invasive Edit link button which turns into a Update / Cancel  links

It seems that the article http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/4afd676c-693b-40e2-ac86-129429c71078.aspx

mentions that

> " So, e.Cells[0] gives you the first table cell. If you have placed this column at some other position (end of all the other columns, for example) then you should change the index accordingly. Controls[0] gives you reference of the Update button. "

1. I do not know that  Controls[0]  is the update button    ?
2. How would I how the Cells[?] of the update button as well ?

**Error:**

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'.


  LinkButton updateBtn = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
  Line 339:                 string updateScript =      ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(updateBtn, "");
  Line 340:                 Button1.Attributes["onclick"] = updateScript;
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" />
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" Caption='<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="CornflowerBlue"><tr><td><B>NORTH</B></td></tr></table>'
                            CaptionAlign="Top" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" Width="100%" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged">
```

**Code:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)            

if (e.Row.RowIndex == GridView1.EditIndex) {  

LinkButton updateBtn = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
string updateScript = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(updateBtn, "");
Button1.Attributes["onclick"] = updateScript;

string cancelScript = string.Format("javascript:__doPostBack('{0}','Cancel${1}')", GridView1.ID, e.Row.RowIndex);
Button2.Attributes["onclick"] = cancelScript;
```

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

If I delete a visible=false from a Edit button this is the HTML in the gridview

```
 <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true"  EditText="edit" ItemStyle-Width="5px">
                                    <ItemStyle Width="5px"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:CommandField>
```

Chrome Browser view a row in edit mode

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1$_ctl12$_ctl0','')">Update</a>
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Cancel$10')">Cancel</a>
```

This code works as expected...

*However The Update / Cancel button above the grid are **not** getting the correct information*

```
<a onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('Button11','');" id="Button11" href="javascript:__doPostBack('Button11','')">Update</a>
<a onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Cancel$10');" id="Button22" href="javascript:__doPostBack('Button22','')">Cancel</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access the buttons with their given ID in the code behind since they are not part of the gridview. Try replacing

```
LinkButton updateBtn = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
```

with

```
Button updateBtn = Button1;
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'

Comment: I'm not sure why it is a LinkButton...  ugh

Comment: You could really eliminate the entire line and reference Button1 in your second line. Example: `string updateScript = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Button1, "");`

Comment: I changed it to Button updateBtn = Button1;   but the update button is not updating

Comment: I'm realizing that now, ...  I changed from button to linkbutton and that didn't help   - yes I need to change to add an event  .. I thought that code was doing that , but I can see why it would not be able to do that especially for the update,  the cancel button seems like it would be more apt to work

Comment: My apologies, the button is gaining an onclick event on this line: `Button1.Attributes["onclick"] = updateScript;`. Can you paste more of your gridview code? Looking further at the link you provided, you should still have the Edit/Cancel on each line on the grid, they are just being hidden. So your original code is near correct, you are likely just selecting the wrong control with Control[0]. There may be other controls in the same cell.

Comment: Have you tried changing this line from a LinkButton to a LiteralControl? `LinkButton updateBtn = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];` to `LiteralControl updateBtn = (LiteralControl )e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];`

Comment: offhand it seems that since the buttons above have no idea about what row that they are on,  they need to be updated with the proper _doPostBack('GridView1$_ctl12$_ctl0','')     THAT  , OR the button looks to call the postback available update link on the page that I just make not visible.

Comment: I didn't try changing to a LiteralControl,  I am pretty sure that the reason at first I had that error is that this code  e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];  referenced a literalcontrol  ,   The other issue is that I'm not even on a row , well I do want to capture what row i'm on though

Comment: Well that did get it much closer with LiteralControl  However Here is are the buttons which do not work <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Update" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView2:_ctl8:_ctl1','');" language="javascript" id="Button1">   <input type="submit" name="Button2" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Cancel$6');" language="javascript" id="Button2">   THEN the row links that WORK    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1$_ctl8$_ctl0','')">Update</a>  <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Cancel$6')">Cancel</a>

Comment: Somehow Update button is   GridView2:_ctl8:_ctl1','')   BUT IT SHOULD BE 'GridView1$_ctl8$_ctl0',''